# Decoding loop logic from matroska (mkv, webm) to audio (C++ via libvorbis)

Tags: c++, audio, oggvorbis, matroska

*(I'm not fluent in english i'll try to do my best)*

I try to code (C++) a simple mkv player. I'm very new in this subject, so I discover all I need little by little. For the beginning, I use VP8 codec for video and Vorbis for audio.
The video side seem ok for now, but I'm in trouble with audio.

I can't figure out the loop logic to decode the audio frames I get from *mkvparser* with the *libvorbis*.
I looked up to [this sample](https://svn.xiph.org/trunk/vorbis/examples/decoder_example.c) and [this brief explanation](http://n.ethz.ch/student/mrossini/howto/howto-libogg.html#decoding) but can't manage to make it work in my case. And I didn't find other simple examples.

Here is a chunk of my code:

```
const mkvparser::Block* const pBlock = m_pMkvContext->pBlockEntry->GetBlock();
const mkvparser::Track* const pTrack = m_pMkvContext->pTracks->GetTrackByNumber( (unsigned long)pBlock->GetTrackNumber() );

if ( pTrack != NULL )
{
    const long long trackType  = pTrack->GetType();
    const int       frameCount = pBlock->GetFrameCount();

    if ( frameCount > 0 )
    {
        const mkvparser::Block::Frame& oFrame = pBlock->GetFrame( 0 );
        unsigned char* pData = (unsigned char*)malloc( (size_t)oFrame.len );
        oFrame.Read( &m_pMkvContext->oReader, pData );

        if ( trackType == mkvparser::Track::kVideo )
        {
            // i'm ok here
        }
        else if ( trackType == mkvparser::Track::kAudio )
        {
            // what to do here with my audio frame data ?
        }
        free( pData );
    }
}
```

And maybe the way I get frames is good for video and not for audio...

Do you guys know some good resources to share about it? Or some advices?

Thanks for help !

[EDIT] : I forgot to add one of my try:

```
bool MoviePlayer::DecodeAudioData( unsigned char* pData, uint32 iSize )
{
    int ret;
    char* pBuffer = NULL;
    pBuffer = ogg_sync_buffer( &m_pOVContext->oOggSyncState, iSize );
    memcpy( pBuffer, pData, iSize );
    ogg_sync_wrote( &m_pOVContext->oOggSyncState, iSize );

    ret = ogg_sync_pageout( &m_pOVContext->oOggSyncState, &m_pOVContext->oOggPage );
    ret = ogg_stream_init( &m_pOVContext->oOggStreamState, ogg_page_serialno(&m_pOVContext->oOggPage) );
    ret = ogg_stream_pagein( &m_pOVContext->oOggStreamState, &m_pOVContext->oOggPage );
    int iPacketsCount = ogg_page_packets( &m_pOVContext->oOggPage );
    for ( int i = 0; i < iPacketsCount; ++i )
    {
        ret = ogg_stream_packetout(&m_pOVContext->oOggStreamState, &m_pOVContext->oOggPacket);
        // do something with the packet...
    }

    return true;
}
```

It crashes at *ogg_sync_pageout*, as my *ogg_page* was not correctly initialized.
But, not coming from a proper .ogg file as in the examples i found, i don't know how to correctly initialize the vorbis structures.

Answer (score 1):

https://matroska.org/technical/specs/codecid/index.html
in A_VORBIS section
The private data contains the first three Vorbis packet in order....

and the codec private is here
https://matroska.org/technical/specs/index.html
"CodecPrivate   3   [63][A2]"